# Issues fetching FRED data using getSymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

```
library(FinancialInstrument)
library(TTR)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(fredr)

symbols <- c("DEXUSEU", "DEXJPUS", "DEXSZUS", "DEXCAUS")

exchange_rate(symbols, currency = "USD", multiplier = 1)
```

create a new environment to store symbols

```
symEnv <- new.env()
```

`getSymbols` and assign the symbols to the symEnv environment

```
getSymbols(symbols, from = '2000-01-01', src= "FRED", to = '2015-12-31', env = symEnv)
```

xts object of the monthly adjusted close prices

```
symbols.close <- do.call(merge, eapply(symEnv, MonthlyAd))
```

monthly returns

```
monthly.returns <- ROC(x = symbols.close, n = 1, type = "discrete", na.pad = TRUE)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
> getSymbols(symbols, from = '2000-01-01',src= "FRED", to = '2015-12-31', env = symEnv)
[1] "DEXUSEU" "DEXJPUS" "DEXSZUS" "DEXCAUS"
> # xts object of the monthly adjusted close prices
> symbols.close <- do.call(merge, eapply(symEnv, MonthlyAd))
Error in Ad(to.monthly(x, indexAt = "lastof", drop.time = TRUE, name = sym)) : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Adjusted"
In addition: Warning message:
In to.period(x, "months", indexAt = indexAt, name = name, ...) :
```

Show Traceback

```
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in Ad(to.monthly(x, indexAt = "lastof", drop.time = TRUE, name = sym)) : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Adjusted" > 
> # monthly returns
> monthly.returns <- ROC(x = symbols.close, n = 1, type = "discrete", na.pad = TRUE)
Error in is.xts(x) : object 'symbols.close' not found
>
```

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a separate environment, you can just use lapply to get everything you need and get a list output.

I'm only using quantmod and TTR to show everything. The other packages in your example are not needed to get rid of the error. Do note that quantmod doesn't do anything with the date options when requesting the fred data. You need to filter the data later by yourself. See example in the code.

```
library(quantmod)
#library(TTR)

symbols <- c("DEXUSEU", "DEXJPUS", "DEXSZUS", "DEXCAUS")


out <- lapply(symbols, getSymbols, src= "FRED", auto.assign = FALSE)
names(out) <- symbols


symbols.close <- do.call(merge, out)
head(symbols.close)
               DEXUSEU DEXJPUS DEXSZUS DEXCAUS
1971-01-04      NA  357.73  4.3180  1.0109
1971-01-05      NA  357.81  4.3117  1.0102
1971-01-06      NA  357.86  4.3113  1.0106
1971-01-07      NA  357.87  4.3103  1.0148
1971-01-08      NA  357.82  4.3109  1.0154
1971-01-11      NA  357.95  4.3102  1.0159

# filter data to years 2000 and higher. See examples with `?xts`
symbols.close <- symbols.close["2000/"]

head(symbols.close)

           DEXUSEU DEXJPUS DEXSZUS DEXCAUS
2000-01-03  1.0155  101.70  1.5808  1.4465
2000-01-04  1.0309  103.09  1.5565  1.4518
2000-01-05  1.0335  103.77  1.5526  1.4518
2000-01-06  1.0324  105.19  1.5540  1.4571
2000-01-07  1.0294  105.17  1.5623  1.4505
2000-01-10  1.0252  105.28  1.5704  1.4568

monthly.returns <- TTR::ROC(x = symbols.close, n = 1, type = "discrete", na.pad = TRUE)
head(monthly.returns)
                DEXUSEU       DEXJPUS       DEXSZUS      DEXCAUS
2000-01-03           NA            NA            NA           NA
2000-01-04  0.015164943  0.0136676500 -0.0153719636  0.003664017
2000-01-05  0.002522068  0.0065961781 -0.0025056216  0.000000000
2000-01-06 -0.001064344  0.0136841091  0.0009017133  0.003650641
2000-01-07 -0.002905850 -0.0001901321  0.0053410553 -0.004529545
2000-01-10 -0.004080047  0.0010459256  0.0051846636  0.004343330
```